# What's the clojure equivalent of Nokogiri (for xml parsing with xpath and css selectors)

Tags: xml, clojure, css-selectors, nokogiri, xpath

I'm looking for a Clojure equivalent of Nokogiri in Ruby. Specifically, I want to be able to traverse XML using CSS and XPath selectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a word of caution: currently, no native Clojure lib deals correctly with XML namespaces.

To traverse and transform HTML and XML using CSS-like selectors there's is [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/) ([tutorial](https://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial)). The set of predicates supported by Enlive is open so you can easily extend its selectors.